# Term by term differentiation/Integration

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So i need to find the series which corresponds with this function:
$\dfrac{x^3}{4+x^2}$.

I dont really understand how the term by term method helps me here, also perhaps a short explanation of the logic behind the method would help a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, can you algebraically manipulate the function so that it looks like the formula for a geometric series? And, for what values of x does it converge?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that for $|x|<1$ we have $\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n$. Then note that:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{x^3}{4+x^2} = \frac{1}{4}x^3 \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x^2}{4})} = \frac14 x^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\frac{x^2}{4})^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\frac14)^{n+1}x^{2n+3},
\end{align*}

for $|\frac{x^2}{4}|<1 \Leftrightarrow |x|<2$.

Comment: thanks, one thing i dont get- the 4th step, what is the rule for inserting the x inside the summation formula?

Comment: $\frac14 x^3$ doesn't change the radius of convergence since it's entire. And the formula holds for all partial sums.